# Anti-aliased lines using barycentric coordinates in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am drawing a line segment by joining two triangles. Each vertex of a triangle gets a unique set of coordinates as varying variable (vec3 vBC). Then in fragment shader the value that i get for this variable is an interpolated value suggesting the location of fragment inside the triangle. I use this value to determine how far the fragment is from the edge of the triangle, which in turn is used to do anti-aliasing on the edges.

See the problem in image below:
[image]

Notice the jagged edges in Rect 1. This is because i am not applying anti-aliasing to edges BC and DE as these are internal edges. Because length x is very small, jagged edges on the edges BC and DE close to vertices C and D become visible; these jagged edges are longer in length than length x. If i apply anti-aliasing to these two edges (BC and DE), i see Rect 2. This is because smoothing process during anti-aliasing assign alpha value of 0.0 to fragments lying on or very close to edge. So anti-aliased BC and DE introduce a white diagonal line inside.

So my question is how can i possibly smooth Rect 1?

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 DestinationColor;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;
varying vec3 vBC;
uniform sampler2D Texture;
uniform int TexEnabled;
float edgeFactor();

void main() {
  if (TexEnabled == 1) {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut) * DestinationColor;
  } else{
     gl_FragColor = vec4(DestinationColor.xyz, edgeFactor());
  }
}

float edgeFactor() {
  vec3 d = fwidth(vBC);
  vec3 a3 = smoothstep(vec3(0.0), d*1.5, vBC);
  return a3.y;
};
```

In shader code, a3.y refers to the second value (distance between vertex D or C and fragment) in a set of coordinates i.e y represents 1 in D(0,1,0) and first 0 and second 0 represent x and z respectively.

Comment: "*Notice the jagged edges in Rect 1*" No. I just see a black rectangle with some smudges in two corners.

Comment: It is not the original output that i get from opengl. I just tried to show the the position of jagged edges. Those "smudges" are actually sharp edges of of lines BC and DE. I hope you can see jagged edges on lines BC and DE

Comment: "*It is not the original output that i get from opengl.*" So how do you expect someone to notice something that isn't actually there? You're asking about a jagged edge that isn't shown in the image you've provided.

Comment: I thought my explanation and image would make it clear. Anyway, do you understand now what i am trying to convey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is mostly sound, but you need some means to distinguish an internal edge from an external edge, which you cannot do with simple geometry. You need to duplicate vertices so that the vertices contributing to the internal edge can have some unique attributes so they look different to the external edge. That said, it sounds expensive ...

It might just be simpler to create a small texture with has an transparent alpha value towards the edges which is applied across the line width, which is repeated along the width of the line. It would possibly be faster than all of the additional per-vertex data, especially on mobile with deferred geometry processing.